# How to open my Wine Explorer on MacBook so I can use my already downloaded Games

Tags: mac, wine

I had it open at one point but now I can't seem to find out how I opened it. So I'm trying to use my desktop ghost but that requires me to click on the ssp icon that is in my wine explorer, next to all my other downloaded apps. No matter what I do I can't seem to open it. I'm using a Mac, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the instruction manual at wine hq ? https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ  Particularly this one https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Using_Wine

Comment: What version of macOS are you using? If you are using Catalina you'll need to downgrade to Mojave as Wine doesn't work - see [Catalina and the future of Wine on Mac](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=32590).